# Does a mathematical construct exists which explains all theories?

Tags: soft-question, automata

If I am not wrong quantum mechanics is about measurements of different physical properties and probabilities of getting different outcomes. We have a mathematical construct to explain it, that is how state of a system is defined in a Hilbert space etc.

I just know complexity theory in layman's terms as of now. But if I am not wrong a Turing machine is an abstract mathematical construct which can explain the working of all algorithms ( again in layman terms, I know there are different types of Turing machines ).

I am compelled to think that is there a branch of mathematics which deals with abstract constructs. I mean like a Turing machine ( or automata ) explains the working of all algorithms is there a mathematical theory/construct which subsumes all other mathematical constructs needed to explain various physical phenomena's. I mean is it possible to explain all mathematical theories ( like the ones needed to explain quantum mechanics ) with a single one, as if everything was part of a big automata.

I am sorry for vague terminologies, its not related to my work but is something I have been thinking about lately just for fun.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the (very big) field of mathematical logic, or maybe "metamathematics" in particular.

Comment: Category theory in a way subsumes all other mathematical constructs.  Whether it can explain all physical phenomena is an open question, since not all physical phenomena have an explanation.

Comment: As the years go on, more and more physics is decided in computer simulations. Some even go so far as to say physics should be computer simulations (this is roughly what Wolfram says in the big book). This much we can say, physics is incomplete thus any existence theorem about "where" physics fits has to deal with the inevitable ignorance of physics.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook does category theory  subsume complexity theory also ?

Comment: Set theories, such as ZFC, come fairly close to being comprehensive enough that most mathematical objects can be "constructed" within them.

Comment: @sasha category theory is very general, if I understand correctly, it includes just about everything you can think of, or, at least gives a language in which those things can be reformulated. As to complexity theory, I don't know details... but, I'd be surprised if could not be fit... I'll leave the details to those who have studied these things properly :)